# Android: Make multiline edittext scrollable, disable in vertical scroll view

Tags: android-edittext, android, android-scrollview, android-scrollbar

I am developing an application in which i am struct at a point.

As according to my application requirement i created horizontal scrollview in xml and then vertical scrollview in .java as :

```
// Vertical Scroll view in Linear layout
ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Then i created a table view programatically and added it in scrollview. I created multiline edit text and disable it because i want to set text in it run time and added this in table view as a row..

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setId(1);
editText.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0f));
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
editText.setHint("Comment");
editText.setSingleLine(false);
editText.setLines(5);
editText.setMaxLines(5);
editText.setText(CommentFromDB);
editText.setEnabled(false);

tableLayout.addView(editText);

// Add table in Horizontal scroll view
scrollView.addView(tableLayout);
```

Now i want to make edit text scrollable which i achieve by code:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (view.getId() == 1) {
                view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But the edittext is not scrolling easily. I need the smooth scrolling.

How to do that please guide me.

Comment: Why don't you try to using `TextView` , since any way your disabling the `EditText`

Comment: @Libin- can i make Textview scrollable in same case having fix size???

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do one thing.

Just make edit text focusable false. And apply on touch listener.

So user is not able to edit text and it will scroll as:

```
EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setId(1);
editText.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0f));
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
editText.setHint("Comment");
editText.setSingleLine(false);
editText.setLines(5);
editText.setMaxLines(5);
editText.setText(CommentFromDB);
editTextRemark.setFocusable(false);
```

Apply onTouchListner as:

```
editTextRemark.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

and

```
OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
    public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent motionEvent){
        if(v.getId() == 1){
            v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Hope this answer will help you.

Answer (score 7):

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
               public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (view.getId() ==R.id.common_remark) {
                        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        switch (event.getAction()&MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
        });
```

And in xml add this line in EditText:

```
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

add to EditText

```
 android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin use this

```
editText.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
    v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)
    when (event.action and MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ->  v.parent.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false)
    }
    false
}
```